# SLURM Job Array | Statuses of all subjobs

Tags: arrays, jobs, slurm, hpc

I have SLURM 21.08.8-2 installed on a cluster running Ubuntu 20.04. I have an existing workflow that submits a job array. I need to get the counts of failed and successful subjobs for a given array job. I've been reviewing documentation and haven't seen a SLURM variable that would provide these counts. I know I could create some logic to count this but was hoping there's a built-in variable available.

Does anyone have a good solution to this?

Comment: I may have answered my own question. I stumbled on the --states option with squeue that should work 

https://slurm.schedmd.com/squeue.html#:~:text=%2Dt%2C%20%2D%2Dstates,PD%22%20are%20equivalent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One nice tool to track progression and failure of jobs in an array is [atools](https://atools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It is a set of Python utilities that make the process of re-submitting failed jobs easier.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of atools. Wish I had known earlier as that would clean up my workflow.